# Change the content of multiple text files

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I would like to find every instance of "blue" and change it to "pink" in multiple text files. I cannot download FAR (Find And Replace) softwares so I need to use what is already on the computer: Powershell/cmd/batch.

Not knowing how to do this for multiple files in Powershell, I decided to combine batch and Powershell. This is the batch code I currently have:

```
for %%F in ("C:\mypath\*") do (
powershell -command(get-content %%F) -replace 'blue', 'pink'| set-content -encoding ASCII %%F
)
```

This does not work, I receive the error message "set-content is not recognized as an internal command".

I realize that using two languages together can lead to some issues, so is this doable exclusively with batch or exclusively with Powershell?

Thank you.

Comment: Your code says you are replacing `.bmp` with `.jpg`.

Comment: That is what I am doing but I wanted to eliminate any possible confusion so I decided to use colors instead, fixed the question.

Comment: Because you are inside a batch file your PIPE is being recognized as part of the batch file and not the POWERSHELL command.  You need to put your Powershell code within quotes.

Comment: You need to escape the pipe with a caret (and also the right-parenthesis, unless you eliminate the parentheses of `for` command): `powershell -command (get-content %%F^) -replace 'blue', 'pink'^| set-content -encoding ASCII %%F`

Comment: Here is the example if you didn't understand my last comment: `powershell -command "(get-content %%F) -replace 'blue', 'pink'| set-content -encoding ASCII %%F"`

Comment: Thank you both. I am going with Squashman's method. My only issue now is that I have spaces in the path therefore quotation marks are not being read properly.

Comment: Use single quotes `'%%F'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the completed code. It finds "blue" and replaces it with "pink" through multiple files, with a path that includes spaces:

```
for %%F in ("C:\mypath\*") do powershell -command "(get-content '%%F') -replace 'blue', 'pink'| set-content -encoding ASCII '%%F'"
```

Thanks to Aacini, Squashman and Compo for their help.

Answer (score 0):

You should using only PowerShell if you can :

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\mypath" -file | %{$path=$_.FullName; (Get-Content $path).Replace('blue', 'pink') | set-content $path -encoding ASCII }
```